# Is there a plugin that will facilitate displaying a website (static pages, not a blog) content in two languages

Tags: plugin-recommendation, multi-language

I am looking for the easiest way to display the content of a single website in two different languages, do not need translation, I do have my own translation.  I just want to display the same pages, but in one set in English and the other in Spanish.  Could anyone guide me on how to achieve it?  Is there a plugin that will allow me to just retype the content and use the same pictures, layout, etc.??

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know of translating plugins, in all of them you'll have two sets of content (or more), one for each language:

- [qTranslate](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/qtranslate/): free, creates new input fields for the title, and additional tabs for the content. They are all handled in the same post/page screen.
- [WPML](http://wpml.org/): premium, creates a 'mirror' post/page for each translation.
- [Multilingual Press](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/multilingual-press/): free, works with Multisite, one site for each language, and interlinks posts/pages with translated content.

As per your description, qTranslate would be more indicated, as long as you handle the images outside the content (featured image, custom fields).

You could also use a plugin like [Advanced Custom Fields](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-custom-fields) to create styled Custom Fields: one text field for extra language, the normal content text field for the main language, image fields for handling extra featured images.

In any of this cases, the design must be solved inside your theme files.